# vertically centering a left floated div wrt a sibling table element

Tags: html, css

I have something like the below.

```
<div class='sideTitle'>SideTitle</div>
<table><tr><td>r1c1</td><td>r1c2</td></tr><tr><td>r2c1</td><td>r2c2</td></tr></table>
```

I'm floating the side title to the left with the following CSS.

```
.sideTitle { float: left; }
```

This works in that the side title is floated to the left of the table as desired.  However, I'd like the side title to be centered vertically wrt the table.

I looked through some other answers here which seem to address very similar problems (quite a few results regarding vertically centering left floated divs), but I can't seem to get them to work for this case.

Any ideas?  Here's a complete sample which illustrates the problem.

```
   <html>
   <head>
      <style type='text/css'>       
         .sideTitle {
            float: left;
         }         
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class='sideTitle'>SideTitle</div>
      <table><tr><td>r1c1</td><td>r1c2</td></tr><tr><td>r2c1</td><td>r2c2</td></tr></table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Here's what the above looks like when rendered in a browser.

[image: sample result]

Here's what I'd like it to do.

[image: intended result]

---

**EDIT: The solutions from both cimmanon and @RaphaelRafatpanah were correct; I marked Raphael's as it was slightly more general (not requiring them to be immediately beside each other in the HTML) but they're both great! The problem which was preventing either from working was that I needed to add the below so IE would render it properly.**

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: What should be the behavior in the case where you have 3 or more rows?  should the side title be perfectly centered with respect to the whole table?

Comment: @ajon yes, it should be vertically centered wrt the entire table regardless of the number of table rows / table height.

Comment: Divs don't seem like an appropriate choice for marking up titles:  try headlines (h1-h6) or a table caption.

Comment: @cimmanon using an h1 tag instead of a div doesn't help, I get the same result.  I do see what you're saying, though, that the other tags might be more appropriate.  Just doesn't help get the text centered vertically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adjusting alignment is easiest on inline elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/VBfDF/

```
.sideTitle {
    display: inline-block;
}

.sideTitle + table {
    display: inline-table;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but now the side title text just displays on top of the table.  Note that I am using the Microsoft Web Browser ActiveX control to render the content inside a C++ application so perhaps its a browser thing.  Maybe I need to fiddle with a DOCTYPE or something to get it to render properly?

Comment: Nerdtron, that may be because you have one or more objects between the div with the sideTable class and the table.  Look to my answer that may help.

Comment: @Nerdtron I'm not familiar with Microsoft's Web Browser ActiveX control.  If it is using a rendering engine from an old IE, inline-block and inline-table might not be available.

Comment: The solutions from both cimmanon and @RaphaelRafatpanah were correct; I marked Raphael's as it was slightly more general (not requiring them to be immediately beside each other in the HTML) but they're both great!  The problem which was preventing either from working was that I needed to add the below so IE would render it properly.

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />`

Comment: @Nerdtron I chose the selectors that would match the markup provided.  In general, I don't modify the provided markup or add classes in my solutions unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: It is a great thing to be able to gain functionality without changing markup and/or structure.  It would be helpful, however, to explain how your selector works and why it might not work in real world applications, and also to provide alternatives.  Of course, if Nerdtron knew what the + selector was and how it works, he wouldn't have asked in the first place!  So, my point is, it is always better to provide an answer with understanding than one that simply works.

Comment: @cimmanon, that seems like a valid point and the solution is certainly good.  Looks like you can only mark 1 solution here though :)

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah I did know about the + selector, but it doesn't look like that was the key here, rather using those inline-block and inline-table values was what did it.  I don't think knowing what the + does alone would solve the problem as I did know about that :)

Comment: @Nerdtron I know that only 1 solution can be accepted, I am just disappointed that the one that was accepted was a carbon copy of my own with a slight modification on the selector.

Comment: @cimmanon fair enough :)  yours was posted first so I switch the answer to that!

Comment: @cimmanon I would appreciate some credit as well for at least some helpful information!  After all, I did upvote you!

Answer (score 1):

When I want something like that I use `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: middle` for both elements. Not sure how it will work with table.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way 'old-school' suggestion, you could put your 'title' in a **caption** and display the table >< caption  left side

```
<table width="100%" border="1">
  <caption align="left">asdf asdf My savings</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

css

```
table caption {vertical-align:middle}
```

**This is not the best solution** since

- Internet Explorer 8 supports the "left", "right", "top", and "bottom" values
- Internet Explorer 9 supports the "top", and "bottom" values
- Firefox supports the "left", "right", "top", and "bottom" values
- Opera supports the "left", "right", "top", and "bottom" values
- Chrome supports the "top", and "bottom" values
- Safari supports the "top", and "bottom" values

jsfiddle
    http://jsfiddle.net/Jxy4D/

For a better easier solution, just add another TD to the left of your table, and use it has a 'caption', vertically aligning it's content to middle.

Comment: Is there a browser where this would give the appearance the OP wants?  Because I don't see it in Opera or Chrome.

Comment: It doesn't even work in his own jsfiddle.  must have misunderstood the question.

Comment: Hi, no i did not misunderstood .. it's just that i am late. The table captions is no more supported ..
    Internet Explorer 8 supports the "left", "right", "top", and "bottom" values
    Internet Explorer 9 supports the "top", and "bottom" values
    Firefox supports the "left", "right", "top", and "bottom" values
    Opera supports the "left", "right", "top", and "bottom" values
    Chrome supports the "top", and "bottom" values
    Safari supports the "top", and "bottom" values

Answer (score 0):

Now what cimmanon did was great and I +1'd him for that, but what the + operator does is select all tables immediately preceding the .sideTitle class.  Note, the table is NOT a child of the div with the class of .sideTitle so the following code won't work:

```
.sideTitle > table {
display: inline-table;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

However, in your actual code,

```
.sideTitle + table
```

may not be the optimal selector if you have any objects between div class="sideTitle" and the table.  Therefore, I created an update to his code that would work if you did find yourself in that predicament.

Here is the jFiddle for you:  http://jsfiddle.net/persianturtle/VBfDF/2/